# Java - Get ArrayList contents from a text file and output to separate lines (JavaMail API)

Tags: java, list, for-loop, arraylist, jakarta-mail

I am trying to read a text file that has multiple lines of text. Now I want to output this to console, 1 line at a time as this is the format of the text file. Easy enough, right? We can do this with a simple for-loop, like so:

```
lineList.forEach(System.out::println),
```

Now the problem is, I am actually using the JavaMail API, specifically accessing the message.setText method which only accepts the String type.

I would like to know how to output the ArrayList to separate lines in that setText method. I was thinking maybe it is possible to store that for-loop as a variable and call that in the method?

```
ArrayList<String> lineList = new ArrayList<>();

// New BufferedReader.
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            file));

    // Add all lines from file to ArrayList.
    while (true) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }
        lineList.add(line);
    }

    // Close it.
    reader.close();

    // Print each line.
    for (String line : lineList) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

// SetText method from the JavaMail API that does not accept the for-loop  
message.setText(lineList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Convert to String with line separator. message.setText(lineLisit.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I look to this JavaDoc (https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Part.html), I think this should work:

```
// New BufferedReader.
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

// Add all lines from file to ArrayList.
while (true){
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if(line==null){
        break;
    }
    lineList.add(line);
}

// Close it.
reader.close();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// Print each line.
for (String line : lineList){
    sb.append(line);
}

// SetText method from the JavaMail API that does not accept the for-loop  
message.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: If you want \n between your lines, change sb.append(line); to sb.append(line+"\n");

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comment you can use stream to convert list of string to string.

```
message.setText(lineLisit.stream().collect(Collectors.joinin‌​g("\n"))
```

Or else, since **BufferedReader#ReadLine** removes **Line Feeds**, you can avoid BufferedReader. Here is one of the other options.

```
        try {
            final byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("<your file>"));
            message.setText(new String(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Note:** For proper conversion of byte to string better to use proper charset.

Comment: Great, thanks for that!